# Teradata: aborted session due to unoptimal query

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to perform the following query andsession is getting aborted after ~1,5 hours of processing:

```
create volatile table test2 as 
(
select 
    a.*,
    b.client_dk
from test1 as a
inner join  payroll_clients as b 
    on a.payroll_agrmnt_id = b.lbt_lst_payroll_agrmnt_id
)
WITH DATA 
    ON 
COMMIT    PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Table `test1` contains ~1500 rows, `payroll_agrmnt_id` is `unique`.

Table `payroll_clients`contains ~151 **mln** rows (yes that much), `client_dk` is unique

What am I doing wrong?

p.s.: added "show table" for both tables:

```
show table payroll_clients;

CREATE SET VOLATILE TABLE "PAVLENKO-GA".payroll_clients ,NO FALLBACK ,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO,
     LOG
     (
      client_dk BIGINT,
      lbt_lst_payroll_agrmnt_id BIGINT)
PRIMARY INDEX ( client_dk ,lbt_lst_payroll_agrmnt_id )
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;



show table test1;

CREATE SET VOLATILE TABLE "PAVLENKO-GA".test1 ,NO FALLBACK ,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO,
     LOG
     (
      INN FLOAT,
      DOG_NUM FLOAT,
      payroll_agrmnt_id BIGINT)
PRIMARY INDEX ( payroll_agrmnt_id )
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more about the Datamodels ( DDLs) for the two tables

Comment: Do you know *why* it has beed aborted? It's probably not because of too much Spool/CPU/IO, but due to a bad Primary Index of the target table, you didn't specify it and thus it defaults to `PAVLENKO-GA.a.INN`. I assume this column results in a very bad distribution and your table is s SET table = Duplicate Row checks. Try a PI on `client_dk`.

Comment: Hello Aritra, added in the original post, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

The solution was provided by @dnoeth - primary index should be defined for the target table. Thx